# Проблема связанная с логикой в React/Redux приложении

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

React + Redux разрабы, есть вопрос. Сейчас сижу на очень большом проекте. Нужно сверстать страницу. На этой странице есть такой компонент(форма на картинке) и при нажатии на кнопку «добавить»(она лежит вне компонента), появляется еще одна такая же форма. И после того как пользователь заполнил их, он нажимает на другую кнопку и куда-то отправяет данные. Проблема в том, что когда я добавляю новую форму, мне приходится диспатчить экшн и обновлять состояние поля в хранилище, но по концепции иммутабельности редакса, мне приходится весь store перезаписывать, а так как проект очень большой - это сликшом объемные операции. Как реализовать логику в таком случае? В кратце: нужно сделать так, чтоб стор обновлялся только после отправки всех заполненых форм, а не когда форма добавляется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приходится весь store перезаписывать - это нормально. большая часть копируется с предыдущего стейта, реально создается только объект новой формы + коллекция форм + верхний стейт - это относительно не дорого.

Comment: Ну там проект супер огромный, поэтому возможно это будет играть роль. Пока сказали попробовать реализовать по-другому. Может быть что-то изменится

Comment: в редаксе это единственный путь. при добавлении формы вам придется поменять весь стейт. лишние рендеры и пересчеты при этом отсекаются селекторами. другое дело что не стоит коннектить в редакс отдельные поля формы - диспатчите экшн только при добавлении формы целиком, а не на каждый напечатанный символ.

Answer (score 1):

> Проблема в том, что когда я добавляю новую форму, мне приходится
> диспатчить экшн и обновлять состояние поля в хранилище.

Почему приходится? В проекте есть компоненты, которые зависят от этого поля?

Спрашиваю потому, что ваша задача "чтобы стор обновлялся только после отправки всех заполненых форм" как бы подразумевает, что от начала взаимодействия со страницей и до возвращения респонса с сервера, эти формы на весь остальной проект не влияют. А значит надо использовать локальный реактовский стейт.

С другой стороны, у больших проектов, как правило, есть достаточно строго прописанные best practices. Стоит уточнить, как именно надо хэндлить такие случаи, чтобы имплементация компонента не отличался от прочих.

Я придерживаюсь правила: стор - репрезентация модели и общих элементов UI, а локальный стейт - держу локально. Упрощает разработку и дебаггинг.